# Weblogic server CXF error

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic

I have deployed my CXF application to the weblogic cluster. The cluster has 3 machines however its throwing error on just one of them

```
<Feb 19, 2015 8:35:54 AM GMT+00:00> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.apple.gcrmws.core.context.JaxRsContext failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/cxf/common/classloader/ClassLoaderUtils.setThreadContextClassloader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/apache/cxf/common/classloader/ClassLoaderUtils$ClassLoaderHolder;.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/cxf/common/classloader/ClassLoaderUtils.setThreadContextClassloader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/apache/cxf/common/classloader/ClassLoaderUtils$ClassLoaderHolder;
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:141)
at com.apple.gcrmws.core.context.JaxRsContext.contextInitialized(JaxRsContext.java:76)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:582)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
```

I tried restarting but same issue persists. The other 3 are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most times this is caused when you have an earlier version of the library somewhere in the classpath. You can check if that is the case with this particular node in the cluster.

You could also add -verbose to the java command line options in your WL start scripts. That will tell you the jar from which each class has been loaded.